# Set the value of textbox in Bootstrap Modal from label text

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am showing the bootstrap modal on clicking the hyperlink.Beside the hyperlink there's a label in which some text is getting printed dynamically.

I am getting the text of that specific label using jquery to print it in Textbox present in Bootstrap Modal.

The text is retrieved very fine but i could not get successfull in showing this text is bootstrap Modal Textbox.

Here is my Jquery Code :

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".edit").click(function () {    
            var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
            var tdRecords = $(tr).children();
            var CurrValue = $(tdRecords[0]).text();
            var NewValue = $(tdRecords[1]).text();
            alert(CurrValue); //alert is showing the value fine
            $("#Curr_Val").val(CurrValue); //not working
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my Modal Code :

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Information</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                      Current Value :
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                      <asp:TextBox CssClass="txtstyle" runat="server" ID="Curr_Val"></asp:TextBox>
                  </div>
              </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                      New Value :
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                      <asp:TextBox CssClass="txtstyle" runat="server" ID="New_Val"></asp:TextBox>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The value is getting printed in alert very fine but it's not getting printed in textbox.

Someone Please Help me what am I missing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider adding html code that is dynamically rendered i.e. the rendered html from browser.

Comment: DId you try hard coded value for testing - $("#Curr_Val").val("10"); Because the syntax looks fine..And if you can share the developer console for any errors that would be great

Comment: @NagaSaiA yes I've tried  $("#Curr_Val").val("10") ; but still not worked

Comment: Have you debugged from browser?

Comment: @Hamed there is no any error.the value is printing in alert very fine

Comment: can  you provide completed code?

Comment: @AlinaAnjum Try setting value after $('#myModal').modal('show'); and also try  $("#Curr_Val").text(CurrValue); or $("#Curr_Val").html(CurrValue);

Comment: @Dev tried it.still same problem :(

Comment: Maybe problem with accessing asp net controls using jquery way?$('#<%= Curr_Val.ClientID %>').val(CurrValue);? I am just guessing

Comment: @RomanSidorov let me try this

Comment: @RomanSidorov it worked :)

Comment: Glad to be of help:)

Comment: @RomanSidorov you can add it as answers so i can mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with accessing asp net controls using jquery way. You need to change it to `$('#<%= Curr_Val.ClientID %>').val(CurrValue);`

Comment: I was puzzled on it since yesterday..but you solved it...I will give you a up vote (y) thank you so much

Comment: @AlinaAnjum no worries, happy to help fixing it:)